# Wrong javascript file running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In one of my jsp file I am calling the "basicEn.js" in the head

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name=viewport
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/basicEn.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
```

However when I checked from the firebug the "basic.js" is running. Probably, I am missing a tiny thing but I am really stuck.

[image: firebug seems like that]

//basicEn.jsp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your event
    $('li').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'GetPhone',
            data:{id : id},
            dataType:"text",
            type:'get',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                //alert(data); 
                var successUrl = "SelectedFeature-en.jsp"; 
                window.location.href = successUrl;
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: show your basicEn.js code

Comment: @Amy I added it

Comment: put alert in basic.js file and see is it actually running.

Comment: How sure are you that you've actually deployed your current code? And have you flushed your browser's cache?

Comment: @Amy yeah I tried it, its working

Comment: Nothing shown would cause a different file to load. You haven't provided enough detail

Comment: @Pointy I flushed the cache but its still not working

Comment: @charlietfl what do you want to see?

Comment: Look at the "view source" in browser. Something is wrong that we can not see, or you are trying to load this in the ajax which is not clear

Comment: @charlietfl yeah you are right. In page source, there is basic.js instead of basicEn.js. But, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: clearly not using the file shown in your server logic for that route

Comment: Try changing somethng else in your jsp file, eg the `<title>` and see if it updates when you refresh.